# Passing multiple values in HTTP header manager

Tags: jmeter-5.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oc2ry.png)Jmeter Parameterization- Is there any way to pass multiple values in HTTP header manager, can we do it in same way parameterization in HTTP request

- want to add multiple values for token , userid

Comment: what's not working ?what did you try? why java-me tag?

Comment: i have watched videos for parameterization of input parameters. But i don't have any idea  on how to pass multiple values in Http header manager

Comment: what's the difference? try and if it doesn't work , write what's not working

Comment: Yes, i tried it same way, it's working

Answer (score 0):

- Create a csv file with different headers and set different values
  [csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxbeh.png)
- Configure
  -test plan - add Config element- CSV data set config
  -browse and select csv file
  [csv file config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDRv3.png)
- Set value in HTTP header manager `${variable/field_name}`
  [HTTP header manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Tdsk.png)